# Video SVG no render only in Safari

Tags: svg, video, safari, clip-path

I've made a svg with video display inside like this :

```
    <video muted loop width="852" height="480" autoplay class="svg-clipped-text" style="  margin: 0 auto;
      display: block;">
  <source src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); >/vid/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<svg height="0" width="0">
  <clipPath id="svgTextPath">
     <text x="20" y="200" textLength="800px" lengthAdjust="spacing" font-family="Calibri" font-size="210px" font-weight="bold">
       insider.
     </text>
   </clipPath>
</svg>
```

And my css :

```
.svg-clipped-text {
    clip-path: url(#svgTextPath);
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgTextPath);
}
```

It works properly in Chrome, in Firefox but no render in Safari.
I've tried things i've found on stackoverflow but nothing seems to resolved my problem..

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think Safari supports clipping of HTML elements with  
 SVG clipPaths. You could try a CSS clip-path with a basic-shape, not sure what Safari's support of those is.

Comment: hi @RobertLongson .. i need to display a word. Possible with css clip-path ?

Comment: Convert the word to a polygon.

Comment: i've no idea how to make that. 
Sorry but have you an example ?

Comment: Maybe inkscape could convert, otherwise you'd need to look for something that can convert text to some polygons that look like letters. Or write a polygon for each letter from scratch and put them together to form the word.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason an SVG mask doesn't work directly on a video in Safari, so you'll need to create a parent `div` and put the class on that.

This may require a bit of wrangling on the video itself, maybe setting 100% width and height.